# Установка шрифта в консоли с++

Tags: c++, консоль, шрифты

Я пишу программу на С++ и хочу сделать так, чтобы при её запуске в консоли автоматически выбирался шрифт "Lucida Console". Я перерыл весь интернет, но многое я не понимаю в тех кодах, что нахожу, да и если просто копираю они не работают. Вот вроде код который должен работать, но не работает

```
HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);  // Получить консоль

CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX fontInfo;
GetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hConsole, TRUE, &fontInfo); // Получить текущий шрифт

// Поменять какие-то параметры

wcscpy_s(fontInfo.FaceName, L"Lucida Console");  // Имя
fontInfo.dwFontSize.X = 12; // Размер (в логических единицах)

SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(hConsole, TRUE, &fontInfo);
SetConsoleCP(1251);// установка кодовой страницы win-cp 1251 в поток ввода
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

Comment: Уточните в какой консоли  (Linux ,Windows ) или эмуляторе консоли?

Comment: В консоли Windows, стандартный cmd